# In SwiftUI, How can I change the way List stack the row?

Tags: swift, list, swiftui

As default SwiftUI List stack the row by time, which results in the most recently created row is at the end of the list.

Instead I want most recently created row to be at upfront, the first row of the list.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse the `List` so the most recent data is stored on top.

Here is an example with a `button` so you can add elements to the `List` and test it out.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dataStore = [0, 1, 2]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(dataStore.reversed(), id: \.self) { data in
                Text(String(data))
            }

            Button(action: {
                self.dataStore += [self.dataStore.count]
            }) {
                Text("Insert to list")
            }
        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```